# Mostrar solo los números repetidos

Tags: java

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que un número repetido me aparezca solo una vez en el resultado?

Ejemplo de datos de entrada:

> { 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 7 }

Resultado esperado:

> 5, 1

En la salida solo deben mostrarse los números repetidos.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a realizar el [tour]. Que has intentado?

Comment: Acostumbra agregar lo que hayas tratado o investigado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclárate: Que los números repetidos salgan una sola vez o que te diga qué números están repetidos. Son cosas completamente diferentes.

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmarnos si es javascript o java el lenguaje que deseas usar? En caso de que sea Java, ¿podrías compartir la clase principal con su `main()` con el código que has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: Como es posible que esta pregunta no este ni cerrada, tenga 2 votos positivos y ya para acabar ... vienen los hago deberes a responderse lo

Comment: Creo que es de gran ayuda que tambien agregues la etiqueta de que version de java estes usando. Ayuda mucho al momento de resolver un problema.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más eficaz de hacer el trabajo es:

- Leer y eliminar el primer elemento restante de la lista.
- Buscar y borrar elementos iguales en la lista de elementos restantes.
- Si se encontraron elementos en la búsqueda anterior, se agrega el número al listado de salida.

Ejemplo de implementación podría ser:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pruebas {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Datos de entrada */
    List<Integer> numeros = Arrays.asList(5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 7);
    /* Mostramos el resultado convirtiendo a texto la salida */
    System.out.println(repetidos(numeros).toString());
  }

  /* Entrada: listado a buscar, salida: listado de núm. repetidos (sin repetir) */
  public static List<Integer> repetidos(List<Integer> busqueda) {
    /* Clonamos los elementos de entrada como elementos restantes */
    List<Integer> restantes = new ArrayList<Integer>(busqueda),
      repetidos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    /* Mientras queden elementos por analizar repetimos el bucle */
    while (restantes.size() > 0) {
      /* Leemos y borramos el primer elemento */
      Integer numero = restantes.remove(0);
      /* Si había más iguales lo agregamos al listado de salida */
      if (restantes.removeAll(Arrays.asList(numero)) == true) {
        repetidos.add(numero);
      }
    }
    /* Devolvemos la lista con los números repetidos */
    return repetidos;
  }
}
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

```
$ javac Pruebas.java && java Pruebas
[5, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tras equivocarme indicando un Set que solo añade y evita repeticiones, te indico otra manera de hacerlo, para probar y siendo opcional he puesto un generador de números random pero básicamente se puede poner uno estático y a funcionar.

```
 static void mostrarRepetidos(int[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
                if(array[i]==array[j]){
                    System.out.println("Elemento repetido: " + array[i]); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void repetidosOrdenados(int[] array){
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
            if(array[i]==array[i+1]){
                System.out.println("Elemento repetido: " + array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    static void mostrarArray(int[] array){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    static void randomArrays(int[] array){
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        int[] numeros = new int[10];
        randomArrays(numeros);
        mostrarArray(numeros);
        System.out.println("\nArray no ordenado");
        mostrarRepetidos(numeros);
        System.out.println("\nArray ordenado");
        repetidosOrdenados(numeros);
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: El OP está preguntando **¿alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que un número repetido me aparezca solo una vez?**. Tu código permite introducir por teclado uno a uno los números que se agregarán a un juego de datos sin repetición, pero no está obteniendo los que están repetidos, aunque podrías usar la salida de [`HasSet.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) para detectar la repetición y ayudarte con ello para agregar ese número a un listado con los que están repetidos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que buscas, lo he hecho usando los tipos básicos de Java y con estructuras sencillas:

```
    // Inicializar array   
    Integer [] arr = new Integer [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 7, 8, 8, 3, 3, 10, 11, 15, 1, 3, 3};
    String repetidos = "";
    boolean imprimeComa = false; 

    System.out.println("Elementos duplicados en arr: "); 

    // Busca los duplicados 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
       for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
          // Comprobamos si i igual a j y si aún no está en "repetidos"
          if (
               arr[i].equals(arr[j]) 
               && 
               !repetidos.contains("*" + arr[i].toString() + "*") 
          ) {

             if (!imprimeComa){
                imprimeComa = true;
             } else {
                repetidos += ", "; 
             }

             // Imprime los elementos duplicados
             repetidos += "*" + arr[j] + "*";
          }
       }
    }

    System.out.print(repetidos.replace("*", ""));
```

Comment: Tu código no funciona correctamente. Entre otras cosas, prueba a agregar dos números `12` al comiendo del listado. No se detectarán los números `1` ni `2` como repetidos. Y más aún, prueba a poner dos veces el número `1238` al principio de la lista, en el resultado ni tan siquiera aparecerá dicho número ;).

Comment: @OscarGarcia bien visto, ya lo he solucionado, cuando me puse a hacerlo no caí en que tanto el contains como el indexOf da como coincidencia `1` sobre `1238` como tu bien observaste, lo solucioné añadiendo un par de asteriscos que posteriormente elimino. Disculpad las molestias.

Answer (score -1):

te ahorrarías mucho código usando variables Lambdas, las cuales puedes utilizar desde java 8, de dejo un ejemplo saludos.

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


          List numeros = Arrays.asList(7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 100, 100, 200, 200);
          numeros = (List) numeros.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
          System.out.println("numeros repetidos "+numeros);
    }
```

out put : numeros repetidos [7, 2, 3, 100, 200]

Comment: Si el número 7, por ejemplo, se encuentra una única vez no debería mostrarse.

Comment: tienes toda la razón, no he leído bien la pregunta, saludos.